# Google sign-in button customization

Tags: swift

As a beginner,I am trying to change the height of google sign in button, but didn't figure it out yet

At first I implemented as a view but it looked like this and I couldn't change the height

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeLud.jpg

After that I created it as a button, this way I can change the height but the google view is gone

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IIlZ.jpg

how can I fix this?

```
   @IBAction func googleSignInButtonPressed(_ sender: GIDSignInButton) {
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
        
    }
//    MARK: -ViewDidLoad
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupAppleButton()
        setupSignupAnimation()
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self

    }

extension SignupViewController : GIDSignInDelegate {
    @available(iOS 9.0, *)
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any])
      -> Bool {
      return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url)
    }
    
    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error?) {
      if let error = error {
          if (error as NSError).code == GIDSignInErrorCode.hasNoAuthInKeychain.rawValue {
              print("The user has not signed in before or they have since signed out.")
          } else {
              print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
          }
          return
      }
        guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }
        let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken,
                                                        accessToken: authentication.accessToken)
        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error occurs when authenticate with Firebase: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {return}
            let userData : [String: Any] = ["userId": user.userID, "fullName": user.profile.name,"givenName": user.profile.givenName,"familyName": user.profile.familyName,"email": user.profile.email]
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            let db = Firestore.firestore()
            db.collection("users").document(uid).setData(userData, merge: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear @Ambroisa , all you need to do is put a custom UIButton on your storyboard(Customize your button on storyboard UI ) and link it with this property: IBOutlet weak var signInButton: GIDSignInButton!  in your UIViewController.          https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in?ver=swift#add_the_sign-in_button.

Comment: Read point number 3 from below given link :- https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in?ver=swift#add_the_sign-in_button.

Comment: @AbhimanyuRathore I did that but the problem is constraints are not applied to google button, neither programmatically nor in storyboard. It's height is still not equal to apple sign in button just like the first image

Comment: You need to create a Custom UIButton rather than GIDSignInButton  and call google SignIn Functions in that button action. Don't use GIDSignInButton.